# Do to set per-project settings on Atom?

Tags: atom-editor

I want to enable format-on-save (Prettier) on per project basis. I can do it globally, but **how do I do that per project?** I want developers to use the same formatting without forcing them enabling the global setting.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [Prettier configuration files](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html)? These files should be put in the root of your project or included in you Node package manifest (`package.json`).

There are multiple options to choose from:

> Prettier uses cosmiconfig for configuration file support. This means you can configure prettier via:
>
> - A `.prettierrc` file, written in YAML or JSON, with optional extensions:.yaml/.yml/.json`.
> - A `.prettierrc.toml` file, written in TOML (the `.toml` extension is *required
>     ).
> - A `prettier.config.js` or `.prettierrc.js` file that exports an object.
> - A "prettier" key in your `package.json` file.

Configuration files are meant to be included in your VCS.

Comment: As far as I understand these configuration files tell Prettier how to format the code once it's enabled. I can't find a setting which would enable Prettier for one project, but not globally. VSCode has formatOnSave setting which can be set in the project (.vscode/settins.json), but I can not find the same logic for Atom.